# Is it possible to integrate Kite with the jupyter notebook extention in VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

VS code is my editor of choice and I would love to use kite for IPYNB files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Track this issue: https://github.com/kiteco/issue-tracker/issues/259

It seems that it is not supported in the meanwhile.